# How can I make FrameLayout for Video have round corners with Agora?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-view, android-framelayout

At the moment, I tried with this but didn't work.

```
val surfaceView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(baseContext)
        surfaceView.apply {
            clipToOutline = true
            clipBounds = Rect(15,15, 15, 15)
            outlineProvider = CircularOutlineProvider(15)
            setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)
        }
        binding.localVideoViewContainer.apply {
            addView(surfaceView)
            clipToOutline = true
            clipBounds = Rect(15,15, 15, 15)
            outlineProvider = CircularOutlineProvider(15)
        }
```

```
class CircularOutlineProvider(val c: Int):ViewOutlineProvider() {
  override fun getOutline(view:View, outline:Outline) {
    outline.setRoundRect(c, c, view.width - c, view.height - c, view.width/2f)
  }
}
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/local_video_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    tools:background="@color/gray_7f"/>
```

I even tried with setting background with drawable file like this, but didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#CCCCCC"/>    

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#999999"/>

    <padding android:left="2dp"
         android:top="2dp"
         android:right="2dp"
         android:bottom="2dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"/>
```

plus, WebView also has similar issue. Is that related?

Answer (score 1):

Use a CardView instead of FrameLayout and set corner radius, then add remoteSurfaceView from agora to it.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/small_video_container"
                android:layout_width="134dp"
                android:layout_height="134dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="70dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is related, some videos (`SurfaceView`) and web content (`WebView`) are rendered on native side "under" framework without respecting its layout. these `View`s are in fact "cutting a hole" in layout in place where they are positioned and some smart alghorithms are drawing on these rectangles no matter of other framework-level `View`s or framework-related decorations, native side is overwriting this

you can try to use `TextureView` if possible with your player, its like v2 of `SurfaceView`, its respecting (partially) framework drawn params and XML attributes, thats for shure, so maybe also drawables/`View`s covering it

Comment: can you explain more about `cutting a hole`? I tried with TextureView but, it doesn't have `setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)`. Agora Document only provides SurfaceView and it says it needs to use `setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)`. I used TextureView and it seems like the other user can't get the stream.

Comment: make some `match_parent`/`match_parent` `FrameLayout` as root layout, set some `background="#9800FF"`, put in it `SurfaceView` with fixed size, e.g. 100dp x 100dp and `layout_gravity="center"` (centered on screen). now add yet another child to root, e.g. `View` 150dp x 150dp with background #0098FF, also centered. second child is declared after SV and is bigger, so it should cover whole SV, hide it, right? wrong, SV playing video is still visible, kind-of drawn always-drawn-on-top, no matter of other `View`s/`drawable`s covering it

Comment: yes, that's true. But I have no idea, how I can do it with TextureView..

Comment: imho all you can do is to request `TextureView` support from authors... or maybe there is some chance that you can obtain bare stream from API for own decoding and frames rendering, probably also on `SurfaceView`, but with possibility for cutting edges from video somewhere in runtime (still they won't be really transparent with `SurfaceView`, at most solid color in there)